# Python ConfigParser.write() missing 1 required positional argument 'fp'?

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

Code here (left out the unrelated Kivy stuff):

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os

class MIDIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser()
        self.config.read('values.ini')
        Window.size = Window.size
        return MainWindow()

    def input1_comp_move(self, value):
            print(int(value))

    def input1_save_comp_value(self, value):
        self.config['Input1']['comp'] = str(value)
        print(str(value))
        with open('values.ini', 'w') as config_file:
            ConfigParser.write(config_file)
        print('Input1 comp value is ', value)

class MainWindow(Widget):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MIDIApp().run()
```

When I run this I get the error `ConfigParser.write(self.config_file)
 TypeError: write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'`

And when I debug by leaving it blank it requires 2 positional arguments `'self'` and `'filename'`, it didn't require that when I tried to used this another program. What am I missing?

Comment: It should be `self.config.write(self.config_file)` or, if you insist, `ConfigParser.write(self.config, self.config_file)`

Comment: Oh yes it should, that was the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It should be `self.config.write(self.config_file)` or, if you insist, `ConfigParser.write(self.config, self.config_file)`.

Thanks [ForceBru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4354477/forcebru)